# How to write Postman tests to compare a response body with an external JSON/CSV file using Newman?

Tags: node.js, postman, newman

It is well documented how to use an external data file with the Collection Runner in Postman to run multiple iterations. However, what I'd like to do is write tests to compare the response body from a GET request to a JSON/CSV file.

From the research I've done it seems this isn't possible using just Postman. I wonder though if it'd be possible with Newman?

I have no experience with Newman but am curious if this might work. Could you create a Postman collection with an env variable called TestJsonFile and write tests comparing values from that to the response body. Then export said collection and using Newman set the TestJsonFile value to that of a JSON/CSV file (--env-var "TestJsonFile=<path_to_file>") and run the collection with that variable?

This seems plausible to me; maybe I could create a Node project to do it all in one place. I'd just like to ask if anyone has done something similar as it seems like it should be doable.

Any critiques or suggestions would be much appreciated, thank you for reading!

Comment: I was also hoping there is a quick solution for this in the `pm` object with the result already saved.